# Timezone issue: `$ date -R` says `+0300`, but `timezone` says `-7200`

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, timezone

Executing `$ date -R` gives me `+0300` **BUT** when I print the timezone global variable `timezone`, it shows me `-7200`.

Ideas what's happeninig?

<sub>It looks like the DST is NOT included AND the timezone is sign is different, but why?</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by timezone global variable?

Comment: @remyabel - `man timezone`.

Comment: Sure DST is **not** included in the timezone. This is per definition.

Comment: @alk - I've missed that. Idea how to get the DST? `daylight` does not work for this.

Comment: `gettimeofday()` returns DST info.

Comment: @alk - nice, thank you. Can you add this note in your response? (about `gettimeofday`)

Comment: @KirilKirov - do you mean the `TZ` environment variable?  If so, most modern linux distributions should be using the third form [described in the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timezone), that is an [IANA time zone](http://iana.org/time-zones) name such as `Europe/Sofia`.  See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: @MattJohnson - thanks for the info. No, I don't want the name, but the offset. I should have clarified that at the very beginning.

Comment: @MattJohnson: No, I don't think he means `$TZ`. `man timezone` shows an actual C variable, declared as `extern long timezone;` and set by `tzset()` to "seconds West of UTC" (on systems where it exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timezone` does not know about D(aylight)S(aving)T(ime) by defintion. Time zones are constant sections on earth all over the year (**update**: at least their naming was constant during the days [Sandford Fleming invented them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandford_Fleming)). So as referring to those by the offset to Greenwich is common, it would not make sense to add the temporary DST offset.

---

The different sign dues to the different view point and direction of the date/time and timezone.

The offset given by `date` is referring **from** where you are **to** Greenwich.

The `timezone`  is measured **to** where you are **from** Greenwich .

---

Regarding the C system calls: `gettimeofday()` provides DST info. (**Update**: This in not the case for the `glibc` implementation)

Comment: The vast majority of time zones are *not* constant.  See [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Also see the second and third form of the `TZ` variable [in the man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timezone).  Most modern distributions of Linux use the *third* form, with an [IANA time zone id](http://iana.org/time-zones) such as `America/New_York`.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Sure also timezones change, but not on a planned and regular base as the DST comes and goes.

Comment: That's exactly what the time zone database is all about.  It has a rich history and is actively maintained.  If you are not familiar, I encourage you to research further.   Also, the first and second forms of the `TZ` variable are still accepted, but are mostly for systems that do not have the time zone database, and it's only the first form that can't handle DST.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Thanks for pointing me to the timezone database. However my answer was referring to this "first" (obviously old fashioned) way of naming timezones (taking into account the timezone concept as it was developed long before databases existed ... ;-)) to try to explain the missing DST offset in the timezone`s name.

Comment: Yup.  My guess is he is on a lightweight (possibly embedded) platform without a TZDB.  But we shall see. :)  The first form is indeed still valid, and would explain the values.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I renderd my answer more precisely.

Comment: I accepted the answer, as it describes what happens and that's what I'm asking. But, using `gettimeofday` didn't work for me - both fields of `timezone` are `0` and the `man` page says, `timezone structure is obsolete`. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: @KirilKirov: Thanks for digging out this timezone issue with glibc. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

according to my man pages `timezone` is set to

> seconds West of GMT

and I would anderstand that like 'the more in the west you are the larger `timezone` becomes'. So the sign differs from `date -R` and also DST is not included.

You can use  the `struct tm *` obtained by `localtime()` to check whether or not there is actually DST in your environment. If the field `tm_isdst > 0` then it is.